# First click on a control only activates the window and doesn't operate the control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

When my application's main window is not active and I click a control, the control doesn't get clicked and instead the window gets activated. That means it takes two clicks to do something if another application's window is active first.

Some controls already respond with one click, but not others. Specifically menus and tool bar buttons don't.

How can I change this to one click?

Comment: You could add a global mouse hook to listen for mouse clicks, and if the form is currently inactive, and a click is inside its bounds, then search the tool strip items to see if the click was inside their bounds. If so, then simulate a mouse click on that item. I have a solution in `C#`, let me know if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two potential solutions:

1) [Tool Strip Container Tools Strip Lost Focus and Double Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121624/tool-strip-container-tools-strip-lost-focus-and-double-click)

2) http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/122798/WinForm-lost-focus-to-another-application-requires

The second solution seems to have better performance when the menu is closing. For whatever reason, the first solution tends to lag a little as the menu is closing.